# Which Visual Studio extension template should I use?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to make an extension to Visual Studio 2015 and am having difficulty figuring out where to begin. What I want the extension to do is display the cyclomatic complexity of a function above the functions definition, kind of like how Visual Studio displays the reference counter. I was wondering if someone could tell me which extension template I should start with, and if anyone had any further information to help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds very complex for your first VS extension - unless you're very confident/comfortable with the core functionality of your extension and only need to learn the VSIX Side of things, I would start off with a simple extension, and then move onto this more complex one.

Comment: Looks like you want to build: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jean-MarcPrieur.MicrosoftCodeLensCodeHealthIndicator for vs2015. Last time I checked the extension worked with 2015 by editing the extension manifest...

Comment: Hmmm the manifest edit trick no longer works... But it may be a good place to start digging using Reflector or ILSpy